Migrating from TSlint to ESlint
I am maintaing an old Angular 11 project that uses tslint. I have now migrated every dependency to angular 18 and everything works fine. The last thing is to migrate from tslint to eslint using this official guide
But when I try to run the migration (step 2 in the guide) I get following error:
$ ./node_modules/.bin/ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint
Error: The `convert-tslint-to-eslint` schematic is no longer supported.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could you please help me?
thanks
Please see https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/docs/MIGRATING_FROM_TSLINT.md

Can you try with this command: npx tslint-to-eslint-config

thanks a lot - please post this as an naswer so that I can accept it

the question is marked as closed because need debugging details. As soon as it reopens, I'll write the answer. Thanks :)

That schematic is now deprecated (@angular-eslint/schematics:convert-tslint-to-eslint), so from your last link you can find a replacement in this repo:
npx tslint-to-eslint-config

